# close the window after opening the downloaded file

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11

From my jsp, triggering a servlet request using `window.open(url)` that will return an ms-office file . After doing some action(open,save or close), the jsp should close automatically .

```
w = window.open(url, "_self");
$('#choiceSelection').html('<br><br><br><center><div id="reportContainer" class="reportContainer"><img src="loadingAnimation.gif"></div></center>');

//get the child window document loading status 
statusX = w.document.readyState;
chk_timer = setTimeout("chk_popup_loaded()", 1000);
//alert(statusX);

//window.close();
}


function chk_popup_loaded() {
  //alert("aaa");
  statusX = w.document.readyState;
  alert(statusX);
  if (statusX != "complete") {
    chk_timer = setTimeout("chk_popup_loaded()", 1000);
  } else {
    clearTimeout(chk_timer);
    w.close();

  }

  if (statusX == "interactive") {
    //alert("interactive");
    //w.close();
    window.close();
  }


}
```

Is there any alternative to achieve this? The servlet will give response as ms office format file , it will download automatically to prompt us for save or open options. If I open that file current jsp file should close.

I've achieved this in IE8 using readystate  but this feature is not available in IE11. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: What is the code you tried to get  it working in ie8?

Comment: @prem89 updated my post with my code